# Sencha Touch get Response header

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to get the response header after my store load. am loading my store like this way

```
var storectn = Ext.getStore('Contactsstore');
storectn.loadPage(1,{
                    callback: function (records, operation, success, response) {
                        if (success==1) {
                           // Ext.Msg.alert('success');
                           // console.log('response contact api',response);
                           //var responseheader =  response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                            //console.log('response header',responseheader);
                        } else {

                             var responsestatus = operation.error['status'];
                             Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);


                        }
                    }
                });
```

But am not getting response after loading my store, response variable is printinga as undefined in my console.

I tried this one

```
var Location = response.getResponseHeader();
```

But not getting the response, please help me to solve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue like the following way

```
var storectn = Ext.getStore('Contactsstore');
storectn.loadPage(1,{
                    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                        if (success==1) {
                           console.log(operation.getResponse())
                            console.log(operation.getResponse().getResponseHeader('content-type')) // here i will get the response header
                        } else {

                             var responsestatus = operation.error['status'];
                             Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);


                        }
                    }
                });
```

Thanks..